# Issues with promises in a loop. Data is being outputted multiple times. For example, the third time through the loop, it logs data three times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise, es6-promise

**Goal:** I'm creating a Chrome Extension that loops through an array of pages. On each page, it should grab some data from the page, log it to the console, then move onto the next page.

**The Issue:** This is actually working well - except the output is repeating itself in relation to the loop count. For example, the first time through the loop I get:

```
output
```

The second time through the loop:

```
output
output
```

The third time through the loop:

```
output
output
output
```

Here is the code.

Popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.querySelector("#scanInventory").addEventListener("click", getInventory, false);

    async function getInventory() {
        for (let page = 1; page < 5; page++) {
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                let url = `https:/example.com/inventory?page=${page}`;
                chrome.tabs.update({ url, active: true }, (tab) => {
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function onUpdated(tabId, info) {
                        if (tabId === tab.id && info.status === 'complete') {
                            chrome.tabs.query({
                                currentWindow: true,
                                active: true,
                            },
                            function (tabs) {
                                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "getInventory");
                                resolve(true);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}, false );
```

And the content.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    let inventoryTable = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".scrollable table tbody tr"
    );
    console.log(inventoryTable); // This line repeats
});
```

Any idea why I'm getting the multiple outputs? Am I handling the promise wrong?

Comment: Don't add event listeners in a loop. Every event that you fire will trigger all the handlers that have been attached so far.

Comment: Call chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated) before `resolve(true)`

Comment: It's okay to add event listeners in a loop, but it will attach an Event at every step of the loop... so in this particular case, it's a bad idea.

Comment: @wOxxOm - that did the trick! If you want to post your answer as a new reply, I'll accept it as corrrect.